# Google document add-on - setSelection() of text by sidebar button - how to make it an active selection?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, clipboard, google-docs, richtext

**Background:**

I am using the [`setSelection()` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#setselectionrange) in an google marketplace add-on for google documents.

The text is selected as expected when clicking the relevant button on the add-on's sidebar. **However**, this selection is not active - i.e. the selected text is highlighted in light grey instead of light blue (see example below).

*Now:*
[image]

*What I need:*
[image]

This is because the last active portion of the browser tab is the sidebar (after clicking the button), not the actual document.

**Question:**

Is there a way to make the button click select the text **and** keep the document the active portion?

**Goal:**

The whole purpose of this selection is to copy the selected text by `Ctrl + C` on the keyboard, which is not possible when the selection is not active.

Right now the user needs to use the right-click on the mouse and select `Copy` from the menu...

Comment: Does getting the selected text as plain text works for you or do you need to get it as "richt text" (plaint text, font color, background color, etc.)? What will you do with the clipboard content?

Comment: I need it as rich text. The add-on sets headings, bullets and other formatting to SEO articles provided as plain text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your client-side code use `google.script.host.editor.focus()` to make the selection on the editor an active selection.

```
function showSidebar(){
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  var html = '<div>Hello world!</div>'
  html += '<div><button onclick="google.script.host.editor.focus()">Click me!</button></div>';
  ui.showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html));
}
```

---

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#moving_browser_focus_in

> **Moving browser focus in Google Workspace**
>
> To switch focus in the user's browser from a dialog or sidebar back to the Google Docs, Sheets, or Forms editor, simply call the method google.script.host.editor.focus(). This method is particularly useful in combination with the Document service methods Document.setCursor(position) and Document.setSelection(range).

Comment: Sounds awesome, thank you! I’ll test tomorrow and update

Comment: Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Since your goal is to copy the selected text I would like to propose an alternative solution:

The task now will include the copying feature directly without additional user input than the button click. And it will be developed this way:

#### Text Selection

Get your selected text with your Apps Script function triggered by a button click:

```
//... Your custom logic to get the text selection
var text-to-copy = doc.setSelection(x)
                      .getSelection()
                      .getRangeElements()
                      .map(re => re.getElement()
                                   .asText()
                                   .getText())
                      .join(" ");
return text-to-copy;
```

We cannot access the user clipboard from Apps Script but with a `successHandler` we can pass the `text-to-copy` variable to the Client-Side interface.

#### Handling the Server-Side return value

In the following way we can pass the text back to the HTML sidebar.

```
<!-- HTML Interface Index.html -->

<button onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(copyToClipboard).setSelection()">
   Click Here
</button>
<script>
    function copyToClipboard(text) {
        const elem = document.createElement('textarea');
        elem.value = text;
        document.body.appendChild(elem);
        elem.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
        document.body.removeChild(elem);
    }
</script>
```

We can now leverage the native client-side functionality to copy that text directly to the user clipboard without having her/him to <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> once your script finished.

A good practice in this case would be to provide a visual feedback to your user once the copy procedure has finished.

### Reference

[withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction)

Comment: Unfortunately `google.script.run` can't send/receive Class Range object, only the selectetion as plain text.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting solution! However, I need it as a rich text (headings, bold, links etc.) and I believe that ‘getText()’ returns plain text.